# Python Pandas groupby and join

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, difference

I am fairly new to python pandas and cannot find the answer to my problem in any older posts.

I have a simple dataframe that looks something like that:

```
dfA ={'stop':[1,2,3,4,5,1610,1611,1612,1613,1614,2915,...]
      'seq':[B, B, D, A, C, C, A, B, A, C, A,...] }
```

Now I want to merge the 'seq' values from each group, where the difference between the next and previous value in 'stop' is equal to 1. When the difference is high like 5 and 1610, that is where the next cluster begins and so on.

What I need is to write all values from each cluster into separate rows:

```
0 BBDAC   #join'stop' cluster 1-5  
1 CABAC   #join'stop' cluster 1610-1614

2 A....   #join'stop' cluster 2015 - ...
etc...
```

What I am getting with my current code is like:

```
True   BDACABAC...
False  BCA...
```

for the entire huge dataframe.

I understand the logic behid the whay it merges it, which is meeting the condition (not perfect, loosing cluster edges) I specified, but I am running out of ideas if I can get it joined and split properly into clusters somehow, not all rows of the dataframe.

Please see my code below:

```
dfB = dfA.groupby((dfA.stop - dfA.stop.shift(1) == 1))['seq'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Please help.

P.S. I have also tried various combinations with diff() but that didn't help either. I am not sure if groupby is any good for this solution as well. Please advise!

```
dfC = dfA.groupby((dfA['stop'].diff(periods=1)))['seq'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x)).reset_index()
```

This somehow splitted the dataframe into smaller chunks, cluster-like, but I am not understanding the legic behind the way it did it, and I know the result makes no sense and is not what I intended to get.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Right now your question has severe formatting issues that are likely to scare away any potential responder. I would suggest to edit your question accordingly. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need create helper `Series` for grouping:

```
g = dfA['stop'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
dfC = dfA.groupby(g)['seq'].apply(''.join).reset_index()
print (dfC)
   stop    seq
0     1  BBDAC
1     2  CABAC
2     3      A
```

**Details**:

First get differences by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
print (dfA['stop'].diff())
0        NaN
1        1.0
2        1.0
3        1.0
4        1.0
5     1605.0
6        1.0
7        1.0
8        1.0
9        1.0
10    1301.0
Name: stop, dtype: float64
```

Compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) `(!=)` for first values of groups:

```
print (dfA['stop'].diff().ne(1))
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
Name: stop, dtype: bool
```

Asn last create groups by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (dfA['stop'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    3
Name: stop, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.
I managed to round the values of 'stop' to a nearest 100 and assigned it as a new column.
Then my previous code is working....
Thank you so much for quick answer though.

dfA['new_val'] = (dfA['stop'] / 100).astype(int) *100